# Angular-nvD3 resizes chart on data change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm using [Angular-nvD3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3). I have a simple chart that looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
<nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pieChart',
            height: 450,
            x: function (d) { return d.key; },
            y: function (d) { return d.y; },
            showLabels: true,
            duration: 1100,
            showLegend: false
        }
    };
```

My *data* object is just a simple array of objects with *key* and *y* properties. On some DOM event, I update the data from the server and change the *data* object. When I do this, my chart is resized.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

[image]

**Update:**

```
// This is the function that is called on the DOM event.
var loadAllData = function () {
    var result = getData();

    result.$promise.then(function (returnedAmounts) {
        loadChartsData(returnedAmounts.expenses, $scope.data);
    }, function (error) {
        // Error.
    });
}

var loadChartsData = function (group, chartsData) {
    // Iterate over the group
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        chartsData[i] = {
            key: group[i].name || group[i].key,
            y: group[i].amount
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It's strange, can you check [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VYzmqk?p=preview)

Comment: It doesn't really replicate my situation. I will update my question so that you can understand it.

Comment: what's versions do you use? did you try to manually update/refresh the charts via api after data loading?

Answer (score 0):

try to set your config.deepWatchData = false, that way the chart will only update when you tell it to. (by using api.refresh)

[image: deepWatchData]